# How do I convert a Geometry column to length in SQL server 2012, and then to SUM the total?

Tags: sql, geometry

I'm not very proficient with SQL, and this is the best I can come up with so far. I need to find a way to measure the length for each row by converting the geometry column. I then need to Calculate the Sum of this column to miles.

I only have access to SQL Server 2012.

```
DECLARE @g geometry;  
SET @g = geometry::STLineFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 2 2, 1 0)', 4326);  
SELECT SUM((@g.STLength())) AS Total_Length
FROM [TABLE NAME];
```

Comment: Your geometry data needs to be in feet - where is the data located?

Comment: Our data is stored on the SQL server within an enterprise database.

Comment: i mean where in the world is it located

Comment: Oh. It's in California. 

I have a table of various water pipes if that helps for further context.

Comment: since you can't do coordinate system transformatoins in SQL server, you have to import your data in a California State Plane zone projected coordinate system, which we do here using Colorado State Plane Central. Then you can use all the spatial functions that SQL server offers: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/ogc-methods-on-geometry-instances?view=sql-server-ver15 including STLength()